# Работа с BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Имеется расписание занятий, требуется создать уведомление перед каждым  событием. Вроде всё понятно, единственная загвоздка в отслеживании этих событий в фоне. Нашел вариант с использованием `Alarm manager`,думал просто ему передавать время до событий, однако не понятно как можно обновлять времена событий. Так как каждый день события разные. Думал отслеживать полночь и переходить на отчет времени до событий по текущему дню, но не совсем представляю реализацию.

Может есть более красивый и правильный выход для решения данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. Создавать Сервис, для этого он и нужен. Для создания расписания событий используется JobDispatcher это решение тоже несомненно лучше чем AlarmManager. Если будет нужна совместимость ниже api 21, то у него есть аналоги, которые вы с легкостью сможете найти с помощью гугла. Для понимания полной картины - как решаются подобный задачи крайне рекомендую просмотреть курс на [Udacity "Developing android apps"](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851). В 10 главе рассматривается весь необходимый функционал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только вопрос JobDispatcher требует online?

Comment: Нет, не требует. Я немного описался, JobShceduler, и FirebaseJobDispatcher. Сути не меняет но все же. Еще раз - посмотрите курс который я рекомендовал, в 10 главе даны ответы на все вопросы, займет час - другой.

Comment: Посмотрел, спасибо за помощь!